# How to create an array of a specific length?

Tags: arrays, loops, input

I am trying to take certain number as an input and create an array of same length. I know the array is indexed beginning from 0 to n-1, for the array of length n.

I cannot quite figure out where I made the mistake.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class A {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of test cases:");
    int test = read.nextInt();
    String[] name = new String[test];


    if (test > 0 && test <= 20) {

      System.out.println("Please give " + test + " names:");

      for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {

        name[i] = read.nextLine();


      }
    }
  }
}
```

Expectation: for example if the input is 9, an array of size 9
result: if the input is 9, the array creates is of 8

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.next()` instead of `.nextLine()`. It only parses the next element of the command line. With this you could also type all names in one line, because the Scanner separates by whitespace characters instead of lines.

See the Java documentation for further information about the two methods. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that after the `read.nextInt()` your position is after the int just before the line end so the first read.nextLine() in the loop will read an empty line.
You can either make a `read.nextLine()` before the loop or instead of nextInt you can read with nextLine() and cast to int with parseInt() in case you are sure you hit an enter after the int.
E.g. instead of

```
int test = read.nextInt();
```

do

```
int test = Integer.parseInt(read.nextLine());
```

If you don't want to require enter, then you can change

```
    name[i] = read.nextLine();
```

to

```
    name[i] = read.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with arrays but with read.nextLine(). You can use read.next().